# Eclipse plugin deployment in same Eclipse instance - possible?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which will operate in plugin-only mode - mainly special context menus for certain project natures. Is there a way to deploy the plugin into the current Eclipse runtime, so I can immediately test it there? 
If no, how are developers supposed to test plugins which use Eclipse's file explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Eclipse IDE, open "*Run > Run Configurations...*"  Select Eclipse Application and create a new run configuration.

Then on the "*Main*" tab there will be a "*Program to Run*" section.  Select the radio button "*Run an application:*"

Then in it's drop down menu, select "*org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench*"

Now switch to the tab labeled "*Plug-ins*".  Make sure the plug-in that you are building and want to test is selected.  You may have to use the drop down labeled "*Launch with:*" and select "*plug-ins selected below only*" in order for the UI to let you select the plug-in your building.

Now, just to make sure this is all going to launch correctly, select the button, "*Validate Plug-ins*"  If there are errors, close the message box and select the button, "*Add Required Plug-ins*"  This will auto select all dependent plugins for this run configuration.

Now select the button "*Run*" and a new instance of Eclipse will launch with your plug-in installed in it.

Comment: Hey, This solution opening in new eclipse instance. Is there any way that current plugin refreshed in same running eclipse instance?

Comment: +Yashdeep Patel, I have never had a need to do that, so I don't know.  I can think of a way to accomplish it, but it would take a lot of extra work compared to the solution in my answer above.

Comment: +twindham thanks for your reply. Currently issue i am facing is, My new eclipse instance goes out of memory and in not responding mode if i run plug in in new instance. Any solution for this?

Comment: +Yashdeep, try this... In your Run Configuration dialog with the new instance run configuration selected, select the tab labeled 'Arguments'.  Then put this in the field labeled VM arguments:  -Xms256m -Xmx512m  These will tell the VM to allocate more memory for your second instance to run.

Comment: Hey, Still i am facing same issue. Eclipse is going Out of memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be now.  Maybe this would make a good question for you to ask on this site.  The community here is pretty good about helping out.